# Merge rows in the middle of a table using multirow package

Tags: tables, multirow

How can I merge some non-adjacent rows in a table? I'm using a template that uses booktabs, threeparttable, and multirow. I don't have flexibility to change the template.

Here is an example that works, call it `table-ok.tex`:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\specialrule{1.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}

Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4 & Col5 \\
\hline\hline

\multirow{3}{*}{Blah}
    & A & i
    & \multirow{3}{*}{Same Text-1} & \multirow{3}{*}{Same Text-2} \\ \cline{2-3}
    & B & ii & \\ \cline{2-3}
    & C & iii & \\ \cline{2-3}

\specialrule{1.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

But **how can I merge only column 4** in the following?

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\specialrule{1.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}

Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4 & Col5 \\
\hline\hline

\multirow{3}{*}{Blah}
    & A & i & Same Text & Different for A \\ \cline{2-3}
    & B & ii &  Same Text & Different for B \\  \cline{2-3}
    & C & iii &  Same Text & Different for C \\ \cline{2-3}

\specialrule{1.5pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Here is the main.tex for reproducibility:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{multirow} 

%-------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Easy when all merges are adjacent.}
\input{table-ok}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{How to do this one?}
\input{table-help}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you want is not clear to me. Coule you explain why you need \multirow?

Comment: you can use exactly the same markup just with one `\multirow` not 2 and leave the spanned cells blank on later rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have

```
\multirow{3}{*}{Blah}
```

for the first column. The solution for the fourth column is entirely analogous:

```
\multirow{3}{*}{Same Text}
```

---

A full MWE (minimum working example) and its associated output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{How to do this one?\strut}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
Col1 & Col2 & Col3 & Col4 & Col5 \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Blah}
    & A & i   & \multirow{3}{*}{Same Text} & Different for A \\ \cline{2-3}
    & B & ii  &                            & Different for B \\ \cline{2-3}
    & C & iii &                            & Different for C \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But how would I get the row lines in column 5? Is there something like `\cline{2-3, 5}`?

Comment: @a11 - `\cline{2-3}\cline{5-5}`.

Comment: Why didn't I think of that! Thanks